# Can't create tables because they all relate to each other. Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have three tables that depend on each other. because of that I can not create the tables because the foreign keys reference can't find the referencing table in whatever position I put the CREATE statements.

> Error 1005 - Kann Tabelle `coopr_local`.`characters` nicht erzeugen
>   (Error 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
CREATE TABLE characters 
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    character_0 TEXT,
    character_1 TEXT,
    character_2 TEXT,
    squad_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (squad_id) REFERENCES squads(id)
);

CREATE TABLE squads_members 
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    character_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (character_id) REFERENCES characters(id)
);

CREATE TABLE squads 
(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    squad_name varchar(255),
    squad_members_id int,
    squad_callsign varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (squad_members_id) REFERENCES squads_members(id)
);
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't describe what you're trying to model but from what I can guess you probably want to model some game where there are characters who can be grouped in squads.

For that you'd have a table for the squads:

```
CREATE TABLE squads 
             (id integer
                 NOT NULL
                 AUTO_INCREMENT,
              name varchar(255),
              callsign varchar(10),
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

If a character can only be a member of one squad, you'd have a reference to that squad in the character table:

```
CREATE TABLE characters 
             (id integer
                 NOT NULL
                 AUTO_INCREMENT,
              character_0 text,
              character_1 text,
              character_2 text,
              squad integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (squad)
                          REFERENCES squads
                                     (id));
```

In the case a character cannot belong to more than one squad you're done and don't need another table.

Should it be possible for a character to belong to more than one squad, you don't have the reference to a squad in the character table:

```
CREATE TABLE characters 
             (id integer
                 NOT NULL
                 AUTO_INCREMENT,
              character_0 text,
              character_1 text,
              character_2 text,
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Instead of the reference to the squad being in the character table, you'd have a third table, a table linking characters and squads:

```
CREATE TABLE squads_characters
             (squad integer,
              character integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (squad,
                           character),
              FOREIGN KEY (squad)
                          REFERENCES squads
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (character)
                          REFERENCES characters
                                     (id));
```

Answer (score 1):

pick only one table to be the principal one without a foreign key constraint and the two others to be te complementary ones that depends on the principal and have the foreigh keys like in the below example:

```
    CREATE TABLE tblAddress (
    AddressID INT NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Country VARCHAR(1000),
    State VARCHAR(1000),
    City VARCHAR(1000),
    Zip VARCHAR(10),
    AddrLine1 VARCHAR(1000),
    AddrLine2 VARCHAR(1000)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonA (
    PersonID INT NOT NULL Primary Key,
    FirstName VARCHAR(200),
    LastName VARCHAR(200),
    --OtherColumns
    AddressID INT,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Address FOREIGN KEY (AddressID)
        REFERENCES tblAddress(AddressID)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonB (
    PersonID INT NOT NULL Primary Key,
    FirstName VARCHAR(200),
    LastName VARCHAR(200),
    --OtherColumns
    AddressID INT,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Address FOREIGN KEY (AddressID)
        REFERENCES tblAddress(AddressID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create all tables and then add the foreign keys,

With

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-adding